# How did this unedited question get 3 "brand new" tags

Tags: support, tags

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261231/do-moderators-have-access-to-dev-stackoverflow-com-and-can-anyone-access-it-by was recently asked on MSO and there were 3 tags, [fun](/questions/tagged/fun), [humor](/questions/tagged/humor), and [dev.so](/questions/tagged/dev.so) that have no other questions.  The question was not edited by anyone and the user does not have enough rep to have the privilege to create tags, the tags must have already existed at the time.

Tags without questions are supposed to be cleaned up every 24 hours, so if they didn't have questions, how did the survive.  I know locked questions don't show up in a tag search, but I tried a few other methods and didn't see any locked questions on any of the tags, so they doesn't appear to be the issue.  Even if my search was ineffective, I can understand there might be a locked [fun](/questions/tagged/fun) and/or [humor](/questions/tagged/humor) question hiding somewhere, but [dev.so](/questions/tagged/dev.so) seems to be such as odd ball that it makes me wonder if something else is going on.

Do deleted questions prevent tag clean-up?  And do we have deleted questions using each of the 3 tags?  OR is there something odd going on that is allow tag creation without the necessary privileges?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For *most* sites, the *create new tags* privilege is set to *300*, not 1500. It looks like that is the setting for Meta.SO as well.

The user does have >300 rep, so they were allowed to create the tags.

See [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

*Update*: The requirement has been raised to 1500 to match Stack Overflow now, see [User without the "create tags" privilege is able to create tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247495/user-without-the-create-tags-privilege-is-able-to-create-tags)

Comment: Oh, and tags get deleted automatically if they exist on only one specific question for six straight months.

Comment: I guess I assumed that since reputation and privileges are shared with the main site, that it meant that the privilege milestones would be the same, especially since there isn't a separate page showing the privileges for MSO.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi I knew that one, but the presence of the [meta-tag:fun] and [meta-tag:humor] tags may encourage more humor and fun questions, which is probably why your question was downvoted so heavily.

Comment: So would this question be [status-complete], since it's technically a bugfix?

Comment: @StevenVascellaro: meh, it's a support question, not a bug report.