# What is the newly created tag java for?

Tags: discussion, tags

When selecting the [*new* tab for the Tags on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=new), I found the tag *java* created 4 hours ago, but there are no descriptions, no questions and no followers. What is its purpose/reason?

Answer (score 3):

There is [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278535/teaching-spring-mvc-angular). Presumably the asker did not realize that we don't really tag meta posts with the same tags that were used to describe the post in question.

I've retagged that question now.

Comment: [I see](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/278535/revisions). Do I understand this right: you can suggest tags on the fly?

Comment: @Wolf this privilege is granted [at 1.5K reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags)

Comment: Yes (the reputation part I deleted from my comment), but even 1,5K rep users make mistakes. Is there a hint shown that they are about to create new tags?

Comment: @gnat unless something changed, [it is only 300 on MSO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261233/how-did-this-unedited-question-get-3-brand-new-tags).